# Office Dialog API send message to child dialog

Tags: office-js

We would like to use the Dialog API for some extra operations which are better suited to a larger work area. We already have the ability via the API to message the parent from the dialog (`Office.context.ui.messageParent`), however we would also like the ability to directly message the dialog, like a `sendMessage` function, for example:

```
var dialog;
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myDomain/myDialog.html', function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status === "failed") { 
        showNotification(asynceResult.error.code = ": " + asyncResult.error.message); 
    } else {
        dialog = asyncResult.value;
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
        dialog.sendMessage({ /* my payload */ }); //???
    }
});
```

There are a couple of options to pass data from the parent to the child:

1. query string: `displayDialogAsync(myUrl + "?myMessage=...", function...)`
2. localStorage (if on the same domain): `localStorage.setItem("DIALOG_MESSAGE", myMessage)`

However, both of these can only really be used on initialization of the dialog, they do not provide a nice way to do asynchronous messaging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a popular request (and a good idea), but it is not supported yet. Please go to [Office Dev User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and vote up the "Improve Custom Dialog" suggestion there or create a new suggestion of your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in parrent before use`displayDialog`:

```
localStorage.setItem("clientID", "15963ac5-314f-4d9b-b5a1-ccb2f1aea248");
```

And then in your JavaScript file:

```
var clientID = localStorage.getItem("clientID");
```

Comment: Do you know, if this works in Word desktop too? Are the dialog and the takspane 'sharing' a localstorage?

Comment: @huckjulius I tried it but it does not seems to work,

Answer (score -2):

DialogApi 1.2 got a new feature `messageChild`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#use-messagechild-from-the-host-page

Comment: An example of how to use it would be better then a link only answer.