# Cannot check the value of popup after closing it manually in Excel for Windows

Tags: internet-explorer, popup, ms-office, office-js, window.open

I have built an Excel add-in with a button. Clicking on the button opens a popup. The following code works well in Excel Online: we could open a popup (in Chrome), close it manually, and reopen a popup.

```
var popup;
function openPopup(url) {
    console.log("openPopup here");
    console.log(popup);
    if ((popup === null) || (popup === undefined) || (popup === {}) || (popup.location === undefined) || (popup.location.href === undefined)) {
        popup = window.open(url, "popup", "status=1, location=1, width=1000, height=1200, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes");
    } else {
        popup.location.href = url;
    }
}
```

However, I realise that it does not work with Excel 2016 for Windows: it can open a popup for the first time (in IE 11), but after closing it manually, we cannot re-open a popup anymore. `F12` tool gives the following error at the line `if`:

```
openPopup here
[Object] { }
Error 
   at openPopup ... ...
```

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you are using the OfficeJS dialog API. Windows.open doesn't work on the rich clients. Please refer [here](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync) for details.

Comment: Also see the detailed overview: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

Comment: I tried Dialog API, which has limitations. The main limitation for me is I need to send regularly information from the task pane to the Dialog box. It seems that there is no dedicated solution. If you know, please let me know...

Comment: @Thomas Maybe you can solve your problem via localstorage. You can write localstorage from taskpane and read it in popup opened via DialogApi. For sure if popup and task pane addin are on the same domain.

Comment: I need the messages to be sent **regularly**. The Dialog box needs sort of `listener`, otherwise how it could know the task pane writes something new in localstorage?

Comment: Yes, this is a gap in the API. It's been brought up [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817868/office-dialog-api-send-message-to-child-dialog) and is in the product roadmap. No defined dates yet.. it should be available in coming quarter.